# 'multer' works in example code but not in my project

Tags: node.js, multer

When using a simple example of the 'multer' library which sets a server and adds a multer middleware to it in one file it works. (I'm sending a POST request using Postman - form-data with the file sent using 'image' key).

When I try to use the same library inside my express project it doesn't work. (I get no errors, and the destination folder is even created, but no file is uploaded).

In my middleware folder I added:

> file-upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });


exports.uploadSingle = upload.single('image');
```

> api.js

```
let router = require('express').Router();
const upload = require('../middleware/file-upload');

router.post('/upload', upload.uploadSingle,function (req, res, next) {

    res.json({"finished":"yes"});
});
```

The post request returns 200OK but no file was saved in the destination folder.

When I run this single file it works :

> test-upload.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });


app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Why does the first way fail and the second succeeds ?

Yaron

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error.

It is because in app.js I already the library multer is based on.

```
express_busboy.extend(app,{
  upload:true
});
```

If I comment it out it works fine.